# OnClickListener was deleted after I press "Ctrl+Shift+o"

Tags: java, android

+I am self-learning Android programming recently. I followed the source code from a textbook and I found that there are some problems. Can anyone give me some suggestions to solve it? Problem 1 After I click "Shift+Ctrl+o", this sentence was deleted. Problem 2, there is a red line under implements. Problem 3 txv, btn and counter cannot be anounced.

```
enter code here

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    implements OnClickListener {    
        TextView txv;       
        Button btn;
        int counter = 0;
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    txv.setText(String.valueOf(++counter));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Remove the bracket, `{`, after `Activity` and the bracket `}` after `int counter = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you implement an interface in java (syntax-wise)

try this:

> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

then you can define your global variables

```
 TextView txv;       
 Button btn;
 int counter = 0;
```

and somewhere in the class body you override the onClick method, which you already did correctly

Comment: Thank you very much. I have wrongly put a "{" between extends Activity and implements.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a self learned android programmer like you. What I do is declare an onClick function name in layout xml file.

For an example lets say you have one button named Submit. Then in layout xml define:

```
<Button
 .....
 android:onClick="btn_sbmt_clck"/>
```

Now in your java file you don't have to implement anything. Just do this:

```
public void btn_sbmt_clck(View v)
{
   //your code here
}
```

It will work just fine. At least I never had any problem with this approach so far.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that adding a submit button is a simpler way to have the same effect. However, I don't know what is the advantage of using "implements OnClickListener". I think that it should have some reasons.